# Unable to ping or access local device

Tags: networking

I have a very strange problem where I can't ping a router acting as client from one pc but at the same thing I can from another pc which are both connected to the same router.

I have Router-1 (192.168.1.1). There are two further routers connected to this Router-1 and they are Router-2 (192.168.1.240) and Router-3 (192.168.1.242). There is a router acting as a client, Client-1 (192.168.1.250) which is connected wirelessly with Router-3 (192.168.1.242).

There are two PCs, PC-1 (192.168.1.10) and PC-2 (192.168.1.4). These are both connected wirelessly with Router-2 (192.168.1.240). Now I am able to ping Client-1 (192.168.1.250) easily from PC-1 but unable to do same from PC-2. On PC-2, I am unable to open the router page (192.168.1.250) when I type in the browser and when I try to ping the IP it says Request Timeout for icmp_seq.

A little update: I was trying to troubleshoot the issue myself too. When I manually define IP Address on PC-2, I am able to ping Client-1. But as soon as I set DHCP on PC-2 I am unable to ping Client-1 even though I am able to ping PC-1 at all times and able to ping all routers and even use Internet in both cases.

[image: Small Diagram]

I am completely confused and any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What about dhcp servers? Have you turned it off in all routers except in one of them? You only can have one dhcp server in a network.

Comment: Yes it is only enabled on Router-1 (192.168.1.1)

Comment: Routers, routers, everywhere and there was no schematic to see! You do realise that you need different networks between your networks? I would use 192.168.1.0/24 between Routers-1, 2 and 3. Then have 192.168.1.0/24 on the LAN side of Router-2 and 192.168.2.0/24 on the LAN side of Router-3. Run DHCP on Router-2 and in the DHCP server settings, set the gw address to that of router (1.0/24). You're breaking things by using the same network on both sides of the router. Next time, please post a little diagram.. :-)

Comment: I have posted the diagram. :) Well if Router-1 and Router-2 have same ip sequence then how can I have DHCP enable on both Router-1 and Router-2? Won't that create an ip conflict?

Comment: @captcha is suggesting three networks with DHCP only on the client facing sides. There won't be an IP conflict in that design. Why do you have three routers, but no networks to route between? Do you actually mean Wireless Access Point (WAP) but instead you have ADSL routers with Wireless trying to act as wireless-to-wired bridges?

Comment: Ok well I don't know if I am using the wrong term by calling it router. Well There is one ADSL router which is 192.168.1.1. In order to cover the house (wifi signals) I have two Linksys E1000 connected with 192.168.1.1 which I called Router-2 & 3. These are connected with one another via ethernet cable.

Comment: @Saad Bashir Thanks for the schematic! :-) The E1000 is indeed a router. It also has a 4-port switch (LAN side) and wifi capabilities (also LAN side). The Internet Port (Yellow) should be used to 'uplink' to routers closer to your Internet connection. However, if all you're using are the (Blue) LAN ports and WiFi then you can have everything on one subnet and have the DHCP server running ONLY on the 1.1 router (as you currently have). If both Router-2 and Router-3 have nothing in the Yellow ports then I would check that the default gateway set properly (point to 192.168.1.1) on PC-1 and PC-2.

Comment: @captcha Yes well I have them plugged into the blue lan ports. Well when I let my MAC get ip on DHCP it says it is connected to gateway 192.168.1.1 but i am not able to ping the client. But when I do the same manually I am able to ping it. That is what is confusing me.

Comment: @Saad Bashir Then it sounds like your dhcp server is not setting the same values as when you set them manually. From a dos-box type ipconfig /all and carefully inspect the results for the network interface, especially SUBNET MASK and DEFAULT GATEWAY. There has to be a difference somewhere.. Silly question, but the MAC addresses are different on both machines?

Comment: Yes the MAC address are different on both devices. ipconfig /all isn't a valid command for OSX. Can you tell me the parameter to follow ipconfig that I should type in the terminal window